# List[Row] to RDD[CassandrRow] conversion in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, rdd, spark-cassandra-connector

I've following code :-

```
 val result = session.execute("Select * from table where imei= '" + imei + "'")
 val list = result.all()
 val sCollection = list.asScala
 val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(sCollection))
```

I'm trying to create list[Row] to RDD[CassandraRow] and I found somewhere that we need to convert this list to scala collection before making it RDD, but when I'm trying to run this is giving error that:

```
value asScala is not a member of java.util.List[com.datastax.driver.core.Row]
```

Where I'm going wrong and what can be done to resolve this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You missed `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._` at the beginning. However I don't recommend the solution you've written, because it's not scalable.

There is [Spark-Cassandra](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) connector, that can load data into Spark in distributed (scalable) way.

Comment: you mean to say that instead of using session.execute , I should go for spark sc.cassandraTable to fetch records ?

Comment: Yes, you should connect to Cassandra using Spark and operate (query) on Cassandra data from the perspective of Spark (spark-sql).

Comment: Spark-SQL vs sc.cassandraTable which one is more faster ?

Comment: I tried using this :- val result = sqlContext.sql("Select * from table where imei= '" + entry(0).trim() + "'")
              val rows = result.rdd

& I'm getting error as :-
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: table; line 1 pos 14
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupTableFromCatalog(Analyzer.scala:449

Comment: Here is the answer: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#running-sql-queries-programmatically
Please read the Spark programming guide- it's the essence of Spark tutorials.

Comment: Here I found 1 line as df.createOrReplaceTempView("people") so what is df here , it points to readjson,some csv path but in my case there is no csv. I'm so How will I initiliase this ?

Comment: df is DataFrame. You will get it from the Spark-Cassandra connector. https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md